# Heavy Poly Boolean pie menu not working

Tags: pie-menu

Does anyone happen to know a work around for [heavy poly pie menu](https://github.com/HEAVYPOLY/HEAVYPOLY_Blender) not working on latest versions of blender. I’ve downloaded blender 3.3.0 and latest script from GitHub but no joy, I followed the installation process on [Vaughn Ling’s YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRESMUenxa8). Any suggestions very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: 3.2 isn't even out yet, did you really mean 3.3?  Either way, better off asking the addon creator than here.  But if you want to try your luck here, maybe add some more detail to your question.  What happens?  Error messages?

Comment: Hi there @MartyFouts, thanks for your advice really appreciate you took the time. I have been trying to contact creator via fb forum but no joy yet. yes I did mean 3.3.0 as that is latest version here but I am new to all this so I would welcome your answer if I am misunderstanding the latest versions https://builder.blender.org/download/daily/ am I going about this all wrong? No error messages but all other pie menu's work fine in blender once script installed as instructed here https://youtu.be/TRESMUenxa8

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, but some of us only use the released versions from [this download page](https://www.blender.org/download/) and so might not be able to help in this case.  It does sound like something changed in 3.3 and the addon just hasn't caught up.  Maybe someone else here will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I Found the problem, it was me not the software or add-on, thanks for your time sorry I wasted it but I appreciate your help!

Comment: Could you please include in your answer what your mistake was that caused the problem? Currently your answer will not provide much help to other users.

Comment: Apologies. My mistake was to assume the software script was out of sync with the version of blender I was using. The Boolean pie menu does not appear in edit mode as per the video tutorial. However, it does appear in object mode and it does work in object mode. Thanks again for your help and in future I will have a better practised process for posting questions. Thanks again.